# Mysql - how to save url´s as unique key´s

Tags: mysql, url, key, unique

I need to save Url´s as unique key in table:

```
CREATE TABLE urls (
    id int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,

    url text(2000) NOT NULL,

    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (url)
);
```

I cant import this to my phpmyadmin, i get error because of the

```
UNIQUE KEY (url)
```

Anybody could give me an advice how to save url´s as unique key´s in database?

GReetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify key's length so that Mysql can guarantee the uniqueness of the column. However if you try something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE urls (
    id int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,

    url text(1000) NOT NULL,

    date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY (url(1000))
);
```

you will get an error: "Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes" which according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html is indeed the limit of InnoDB tables' columns. Thus I would suggest that you change your column lenght to 767 bytes.